# Помогите сделать запрос MySql

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы

1. message:
   id, from (iduser), to (iduser), message
2. user:
   id, nameuser

Как сделать запрос, из message что бы в результате вместо from (iduser) было имя из таблицы user?

Comment: про [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) не слышал или не осилил?

Comment: и как JOIN решит задачу?  SELECT * FROM message LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = message.from or user.id = message.to даст 2 строки с именами. А мне нужно что бы было в одной строке оба значения.

Comment: значит не осилил... да, и в вопросе нет требования разыменовывать второй ключ...

Comment: В принципе ключи пусть остаются. Нужно что бы результат был примерно такой: id, from (iduser), fromname (username по id), to (iduser), toname (username по id)

Comment: уже ответом дал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы разыменовывать два внешних ключа нужно два `JOIN`'а.

```
SELECT u_from.name, u_to.name, message.message
FROM message
  LEFT JOIN user AS u_from ON message.from_id = u_from.id
  LEFT JOIN user AS u_to   ON message.to_id   = u_to.id;
```

Comment: *нужно два `JOIN`'а* ... и соответственно две копии таблицы `user`.